# Vue 2 - How to v-for a property from an array that is inside an object

Tags: arrays, vue.js, for-loop, vuejs2

I am trying to infer the `time` property from the `TimeMode` array which is inside the main array called `girlsList`, but i have nothing displayed, You can see this [example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-margulis-iklmx)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>The time property is not displayed</p>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in girlsList.TimeMode" :key="index">
        {{ item.time }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",

  data() {
    return {
      girlsList: [
        {
          avatarSrc: "https://i.ibb.co/G0nLSQ8/Girl-1.png",
          girlName: "Milena Williams",
          girlTime: "12:00 - 16:00 PM",
          TypeTime: "Cosplay",
          TimeMode: [
            {
              time: 60,
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          avatarSrc: "https://i.ibb.co/qJB12x6/Girl-2.png",
          girlName: "Milena Williams",
          girlTime: "12:00 - 16:00 PM",
          TypeTime: "Cosplay1",
          TimeMode: [
            {
              time: 60,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul v-for="(i, index) in girlsList" :key="index">
  <li v-for="(item, index) in i.TimeMode" :key="index">
    {{ item.time }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

GirList and TimeMode are arrays, so you need do a for beetween both (two for) or put a position in TimeMode array:

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in girlsList" :key="index">
    {{ item.TimeMode[0].time }}
</li>
```